# Integrally Closed but not UFD

Tags: commutative-algebra

We know that UFDs are integrally closed. But there is no theorem which states that Integrally Closed are UFD.
So I wonder there should be a counter-example.
I know that $Z[\sqrt{4k+2}$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{4k+3}$ are integrally closed. I wonder which of them is not a UFD.

If no such example from $\mathfrak{O}_k$ , exists then can anyone give me an easier to understand example?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3501244/easy-examples-of-integrally-closed-non-factorial-domains

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Easy examples of integrally closed non-factorial domains?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3501244/easy-examples-of-integrally-closed-non-factorial-domains)